# Heroku not displaying all the data in bar chart in Python Dash

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

Can anyone let me know why the bar-chart is not populating the entire data in the first tab, whereas when you run it locally you can see values up to 50 on y-axis? (entire GitHub code in link in comments below). Heroku Pipelines link: https://sewerpollutants.herokuapp.com

Comment: [https://github.com/osonwanne/sewerpollutants](https://github.com/osonwanne/sewerpollutants)

Answer (score 0):

Issued was fixed by updating to dash-core-components==1.16.0